# Insert Column into Table with many Columns Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My first table(t1) is a simple list of websites.

```
url
```

My second table(t2) has two columns

```
url, source
```

I would like to do something like this

```
insert into t2(url, source) where ((select * from t1), '1');
```

But I am getting an error that I have to many rows from my select * from t1. I understand why I am getting the error, but how should I do this query instead?

The reason why I am not editing t1 is that I have many different "t1"s that I would like to mark in my new master table as different with the sourceIDs.

Comment: Why do we even need t1?  A one-column table doesn't seem to serve any purpose when you can do all of your lookups directly with t2?

Comment: T1 is actually a staging table that you need in amazon redshift. Table t2 is the master table, but if I were to insert my data into that table I would have to do it record by record. By using the staging table I can load an entire file into a table, and then use the query to add my data to the master table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the values of the `url` column from table `t1` into the `url` column of table `t2` and at the same time fill the `source` column with the value `'1'` then you can do it like this

```
INSERT INTO t2(url, source) SELECT url, '1' FROM t1;
```